# Is the intersection of dense sets dense?

Tags: general-topology

Recently I came across the fact that the intersection of two dense sets is a dense set.

Take $\Bbb{R}$. Clearly, both $\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q}$ are dense in $\Bbb{R}$. However, $\Bbb{Q}\cap (\Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q})=\emptyset$. How can the $\emptyset$ be dense?

Comment: who says the intersection of dense subsets is dense?

Comment: as you see, it is not true.

Comment: This is a good counterexample to the false statement that the intersection of dense subsets is dense.

Comment: @IttayWeiss- I have to prove that the union of two nowhere dense sets is nowhere dense. Let $A$ and $B$ be two such nowhere dense sets. Then $A'$ and $B'$ are clearly dense in $X$. If I can prove that $A'\cap B'$ is dense, then this is equivalent to saying $(A'\cap B')'=A\cup B$ is nowhere dense.

Comment: that is not the correct way to go about it. Look closer at the definition of nowhere dense sets.

Comment: @IttayWeiss- The complement of a nowhere dense set may not be dense. Is this correct?

Comment: @freebird The complement of a nowhere dense set is always dense - indeed, one definition of a nowhere dense is that the complement of its closure is dense. But the complement of a dense set is not necessarily nowhere dense, as in the example in your question. So you while you can't prove that the intersection of two arbitrary dense sets is dense (because this is false!) the sets $A'$ and $B'$ in your setup have the stronger property that their complements $A$ and $B$ are nowhere dense. I agree with Ittay that this is probably not the best way to think about the problem though.

Comment: @freebird: You haven't accepted any of the answers to your questions. You may want to take a look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 14):

**Result:** The intersection of two **open** dense subsets $U,U'\subset X$ of a topological space $X$ is dense.

To prove this,  it is best to  define "dense"  as: " has non-empty intersection with an arbitrary non empty open subset   $ \emptyset \subsetneq V\subset X$".
So, in our case,  $V\cap U\neq \emptyset $ and then $(V\cap U)\cap U'\neq\emptyset$ also since $V\cap U$ is a non empty open subset of  $ X$ too.
Thus $(V\cap U)\cap U'=V\cap( U\cap U')\neq\emptyset$, proving (by our definition)  that $ U\cap U'$ is dense.

Comment: Only one of them need be open and dense, the other only dense.

Comment: Yes, of course: it is obvious from the proof.